# JavaScript instanceof error

Tags: javascript, instanceof, throw

I'm trying to throw a error as a object, so that I can create a if-statement to check if a error is a emergency-error or not. For this I need to check if the `error instanceof myEmergencyFunc`. But this fails if I have a sub-function. See this fiddle as a example: http://jsfiddle.net/tvs4qjgs/

```
var someName = function(){
    this.LogEmergency = function(message){
        this.message = message;
        return this;
    };
    return this;
};

var a = someName().LogEmergency('my error');

console.log(a instanceof someName().LogEmergency);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: read more about constructor function in JS and using of "new".

Comment: creating methods in a constructor is considered bad practice. Avoid this type of constructor as much as possible: that's what the prototype is for! Also consider following coding standards/conventions: constructors start with an UpperCase, properties and methods don't (all names are camleCased)

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

```
var a = someName().LogEmergency('my error');
```

`a` is referring to the global object and not the object you think you have created(which is `window` if you are running this code in a browser)

`console.log(a === window)` --> will be true.

your final result is wrong because you are comparing with the wrong object.if you are wondering why, that's because you were missing the keyword `new` while creating the object.
calling a function with new triggers the constructor mechanism that creates a new object and returns it.

**calling a function without new and returning "this" inside a function returns the global object.**

you have to make the following changes to your code

```
var someName = function(){
  this.LogEmergency = function(message){
    this.message = message;
    return this;  // here this refers to the new object you created
  };
  return this; // here also this refers to the new object you created
               // here the return is redundant as this is implicit.
};

// new operator is the keyword for creating objects.
// the meaning of "this" inside the function completely changes without the operator
var a = new someName().LogEmergency('my error');
```

in the above code `a` now refers to the new instance you created.
finally check if the created object is an instance of `someone`

```
console.log(a instanceof someName); //will be true
```

Read more about constructors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

Comment: You don't need parens around `new someName()`?

Comment: () is optional if you are not passing any parameters. new someName also will work

Comment: No, you misunderstood me. I'm asking whether you need to write `(new someName()).LogEmergency('my error')` in order to ensure that `LogEmergency` is invoked on your new object, rather than being invoked on the result of calling `someName()` and then itself passed to `new`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Indeed not, though I would strongly recommend using them, too: `LogEmergency`, to me, looks like a constructor. The method itself uses `this`, so `var a = new someName(); var b = new a.LogEmergency('foobar');` is a dangerous game to play

Comment: @BOSS: The invokation brackets in `new someName().LogEmergency()` are _not_ optional. `var a = new someName.LogEmergency();` will throw a TypeError. Either use `var a = (new someName).LogEmergency()` or the code you have, I'd prefer the version Lightness Races in Orbit suggested, thgouh